# Cant update Android 4.4.2 on rooted Thomson QM736 tablet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings

I cannot find System Update in settings. Is this because it is rooted?
Manufacturer: Thomson
Model Number: QM736-8G(HD)

Comment: It is possible that your OEM didn't have plan to update your Android version in future, so keeping that in mind they did not provide provisions for system update, hence, missing System Update app. Can you confirm OEM has made an update available to your device?

Comment: No, I can't confirm